# Safari 9.0.3 flickering issue on window.scrollTo() due to a early repaint on the way

Tags: javascript, safari, repaint, flicker

I'm experiencing an odd behaviuor in Safari.

On a quite content-rich page, upon specific user action (that requires relayouts and substitutions of elements on the page) I almost rebuild the entire document then I call `window.scrollTo()` to move the viewport to a calculated point.

Isolating the problem I found that just before `window.scrollTo()` a repaint occurrs (even if the JavaScript is still executing !) then the scroll is performed causing the flicker.

The document is first displayed with the new layout, then -a frame later- displayed (with the new layout) on the new position.

I explored the variuos "*Safari flickers*" questions (and answers) but none of them covers the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround? The answer below is not workable in my case.

Comment: Yes I did, but for my own specific case (see answer). Looks like Safari has various cases when spurious repaints cause flickers. There are many questions/answers on the subject. Maybe you situtation is different and the answer for you is another one. I wish you find the workaround for your situtation. ...and I hope Apple fixes Safari. Safari is becoming the new Intenet Exploer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour described is clearly a bug of Safari as repaint must **not** occurr until JavaScript execution has terminated.

The web page have a solid color background. After some experimenting I found out that **using an image as the background instead of a solid color solves the issue**.

The main document-sized `<div>` has this background CSS property:

```
background: #eee;
```

Replacing it with an in-line png (a small square with the same color)

```
background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABlJREFUeNpifPfuHQMpgHFUw6iG4asBIMAAYmAssRRucYsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") fixed repeat;
```

Avoid the spurious repaint and eliminates the flicker.